# Is there other a way to deploy virgo-compatible bundles to other application servers?

Tags: osgi, application-server, eclipse-virgo

I am developing bundles in Eclipse Virgo, but I have faced customers in the past who insist on using a specific application server such as WebLogic. Is there a way to use OSGi on every Java EE appliction server?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582709/osgi-and-application-servers) help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no. Some application servers — such as Virgo, Glassfish, IBM Websphere etc — directly support OSGi deployment, but they support it in different ways. Other application servers have no built-in support for OSGi.

However even in application servers with no OSGi support, it is possible to embed OSGi within a traditional Java EE deployment artifact such as a WAR or EAR file. Some example code for embedding OSGi is shown in a [blog post](http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html) I wrote some time ago.

Comment: Neil's right in general, but if you pick app servers that directly support OSGi deployment, you can in principle develop application bundles which will run on Virgo as well as other app servers. You just have to deploy the bundles in app server specific ways. That's a benefit of OSGi being a standard.

Comment: Thanks Glyn. I did indeed mean that the *deployment* aspects differ between these servers, but totally agree that the code can be portable.