# OSGi container and application server container in AEM

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

In standalone AEM installation, Is felix OSGi container present inside jetty servlet container ? Or is the Jetty Server is installed as a bundle in Felix OSGi container ?

Which one will start first when AEM is started ?

And how will this change for a WAR based installation?

According to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582709/osgi-and-application-servers) answer both are possible. But I want to know which approach is followed in AEM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AEM standalone (using quickstart) starts the felix framework and deploys jetty as bundle inside.

You can check this by starting AEM and then open [the system console](http://localhost:4502/system/console). In the bundle list you will find [org.apache.felix.http.jetty](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html). This is the felix implementation of the OSGi http service spec and embeds the jetty server.

Comment: What happens when AEM is installed as WAR in an application server ?

Comment: When you install as a war then it starts felix inside and uses org.apache.felix.http.proxy to leverage the outer container.